# Django custom field with 2 fields

Tags: django, model, field

I found a markdown editor that I'm adapting to make it work well with Django. I would like to have a field to store the raw markdown and one for the compiled HTML for optimization purposes. I want to create a custom field and widget to hide the complexity and make it reusable everywhere on my website.
In this custom field, I would like to have two textfields but I didn't find if it was possible.
My other solutions are :

- to have a model with those two fields and my custom field is actually a foreign key to this model. I like this one because doing some migration for everything is really easy, maybe the implementation will be somewhat tricky.
- to create a abstract model with those two fields. I override the save method to fill the html entry

Comment: You want a field to store boty raw markdown and html?

Answer (score 2):

*Use the right tool for the job(tm).*

- Use a custom field to handle **one** python object to be stored in **one** field. The goal here is translate from storage format to functional object and vice versa. It's possible to use multiple fields, but tricky. See the [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) as an example.
- Use inheritance to augment models with *one or more* fields, methods, what you want. The goal here is to be able to reuse code.

  ```
  class CompilableMarkdownBase(models.Model):
      markdown = models.TextField(default='[//]: # (Start Markdown here)')
      compiled_html = models.TextField(editable=False, null=True)

      def clean(self):
          if self.markdown != models.NOT_PROVIDED:
              self.compiled_html = compile_html(self.markdown)

      class Meta:
          abstract = True
  ```

We do this in clean(), not save, as it's made for it: altering submitted form data or database storage based on other fields. Since python supports multiple inheritance, you can tack it on any model. Using [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org) as an example:

```
class ProductPage(Page, CompilableMarkdownBase):
    pass
```

Just be aware of field name clashes, which you can check with `./manage.py check`.

Comment: Would it make sense to create a custom field that is actually a foreign key to my model that have both information ?

Comment: You can use ImageField as an example if you go the custom field route. The two advantages are that you're not tied to fixed field names (markdown and compiled_html in my example) and you can use multiple markdown fields, each with their own compiled html on one model. As you can see from ImageField the complexity introduced (and thus performance) is vast, so you have to consider if the advantages address real world concerns.

Comment: Yes, I have to use a custom field, I have some models that hold multiple textfield that would requires markdown. I don't really understand how to make a custom field with multiple value inside. I thought of creating a custom OneToOneField to my model with markdown and compiled_html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define two fields to keep the markdown text and compile HTML text, and override the `save` method of your model. Then call your HTML compile method  every time you want to save the model. Your code may look like this:

```
class Article(model.Model):
    markdown = model.TextField('markdown text')
    html = model.TextField('html text')

    def save(self):
        self.html = html_compile(self.markdown) # <-- replace with your html  compile function here
        super(Article, self).save()
```

With this approach, you can always keep your `html` field up-to-date with the `markdown` field. `html` field is updated automatically when model save, so you don't need to assign any value to it before calling the model `save` method.